# Prove that $\int_0^1f'(x)dx \leq f(1) - f(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x)$ be a non-decreasing function on $[0, 1].$ You may assume that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere.  Prove that

$\int_0^1f'(x)dx \leq f(1) - f(0)$.

I am having a hard time with this question.  Obviously we know that $f$ is continuous.  It looks a lot like absolute continuity.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is only differentiable a.e.

Comment: @chubakueno: The Cantor function is differentiable a.e., with derivative zero, so strict inequality $\int f' < f(1) - f(0)$ is possible.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)={ f(x+1/n)-f(x)\over1/n}$. Note $(f_n)$ converges a.e. to $f'$. Note $\int_a^b f_n(x)=n\int_b^{b+1/n} f(x)\,dx -n\int_a^{a+1/n} f(x)\,dx$. Use Fatou.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Awesome. You beat me to it :). However, I strongly believe that you should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

More generally, it holds for $f$ a non-decreasing function on $[a,b]$ ($f$ is then differentiable a.e. on $[a,b]$):

For $x>b$, let $f(x)=f(b)$.

For each $n$, let $$f_n(x)={f(x+1/n)-f(x)\over 1/n}.$$

Note that
$$\eqalign{
\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx&=n\int_b^{b+1/n} f(x)-n\int_a^{a+1/n}f(x)\,dx\cr
&\le
 n\int_b^{b+1/n} f(b )\,dx-n\int_a^{a+1/n}f(a)\,dx\cr
&= f(b)-f(a).
}
$$

Now use this result, the fact that the sequence $(f_n)$ of nonnegative functions converges to $f'$ almost everywhere, and Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: Nice proof. I was going to complain that $f(b)$ should be $f(b+1/n)$, which makes things fiddly if $f$ is not continuous at $b$, but then I noticed "for $x > b$, let $f(x) = f(b)$", which works around the fiddliness rather nicely. :-)