# A particular case of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. 
Prove that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and$$\int \limits _a^bf'(x)\,dx\leq f(b)-f(a).$$I've been told that this is a particular case of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, but I don't know how can we derive this from it. 
Also, this seems to be a way simpler case, so maybe there is a simpler proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3109689/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918612/42969.

Comment: Proving that $f$ is differentiable a.e. is highly nontrivial.